# ArrayFun with multiple input

Tags: matlab

I have a problem while using Arrayfun in Matlab. I have a vector of angles and I want to avoid a `for loop` and I apply:

```
rmatrix1 = arrayfun(...
    @(x) anglesLoop(iblade, iradius, jradius, ifrequency, x, rot), ...
    angles, 'uniformoutput', false);
```

Where  `iblade = 1`, `iradius = 1`, `jradius = 1`, `ifrequency = 1` and `rot = 0.5`.

The function looks like:

```
%% Angles Loop
function rmatrix = anglesLoop(iblade, iradius, jradius, ifrequency, angles, rot)
global frequency blade
fshifted =(frequency(ifrequency)-angles*rot);
S11 = kaimal(fshifted);
S22 = S11;                 
r = distance(iradius,jradius,angles);
aux = (3/(2*pi)).*coherence(r).*exp(-1i*angles*ifrequency*blade(iblade)/3);                
rmatrix = (sqrt(S11).*sqrt(S22).*aux.*exp(1i*2*pi.*angles.*1/3));
end
```

with the subfunctions

```
%% distance for coherence function
function r=distance(x1,x2,theta)

r = sqrt(x1^2+x2^2- 2*x1*x2*cos(theta));
end
```

And

```
%% Coherence
function gamma=coherence(r)
global frequency v10 L1
if r==0
   gamma=1;
else
   gamma=exp(-12.*sqrt((frequency.*r./v10).^2+(0.12.*r./L1).^2));
end
```

The problem is that when I apply the `anglesLoop` function in `arrayfun` I obtain a cell of 64 different arrays whereas I should obtain a vector of 64 which is the angles length. 
rmatrix1 should be a vector of 64 elements. Can someone give me some recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you're asking for `'UniformOutput', false` which causes the return to be a `cell` array. You then simply need to concatenate the contents of the cell array, which you can do with `cell2mat`. Here's a simpler example. I've got a row vector, and I'm applying a function that turns each element into a 2x2 matrix. I want to end up with all of these small matrices concatenated together.

```
rowVector = 1:5;
myFcn = @(x) [x, -x; -x, x];
separateMatricesCell = arrayfun(myFcn, rowVector, 'UniformOutput', false);
concatenatedMatrices = cell2mat(separateMatricesCell)
```